# Set variable 2 equals to variable 1

Tags: batch-file

I thought this would be quite simple task, but I can figure out how to do it

I'm trying to set variable 2 equals to variable 1

```
set var1=xxx
echo %var1%
set %var2%=%var1%
echo %var2%
```

My goal is of course to see xxx as output the second time, but instead I get an error "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

/L

Comment: `set var2=%var1%`. You don't want to create a variable named by the *value*  of `var2` (which is empty in your example)

Comment: Stupid me !
Thanks Stephan

Comment: You are getting a syntaxt error because... Your syntax is incorrect. Variables are only expnaded when their value is being used or assessed, not when they are being assigned a value. `Set var1=xxx` is correct, however `Set "var1=xxx"` is safer. `Set %var2%=%var1%` is incorrect - it expands to `Set =xxx`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `set %var2%=%var1%` to `set var2=%var1%`.